# No sound when playing video from PowerPoint presentation over Skype

Tags: audio, video, microsoft-powerpoint, skype

I have a powerpoint presentation which includes a video, and I'm meant to present this through Skype (or Teams - but I have no way to test this on Teams before the day I'll be presenting)

Initially when testing I had some problems with the other person seeing the video at all: the picture was just stuttering a lot and no audio. After going through media compression the video plays smoothly, but they still receive no audio whatsoever (whereas voice is 100% fine).

The volume of the video is set to "medium" on the powerpoint presentation, so it's not that.
I am wondering if it's a compatibility issue with Skype (but it seems strange, it's a normal 15-second MP4 file), or if somehow Skype is only accepting sounds that come through the microphone (ie my voice) rather than those that come from the computer itself (which would be ever stranger).

I have run out of ideas on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I just googled "Skype play sound from computer" and this was the first result:

Step 1

Right-click the “Speakers” icon on your Windows taskbar. Select “Recording Devices.”

Step 2

Right click an empty space on the “Select a recording device” pane and click “Show Disabled Devices.” You will see a new device titled “Stereo Mix.” Right-click this and select “Enable.”

Step 3

Click “OK” to close the “Recording Devices” pane. Open Skype.

Step 4

Click “Tools” and select “Options” in the Skype application.

Click the “Audio Settings tab.” Click the drop-down next to “Microphone” and select “Stereo Mix” from the available options. Click “Save” to apply the changes. Once saved, all audio on your computer, including that of your microphone and open applications, will be audible to anyone you're communicating with via Skype

The next time you want to ask a question, it always helps to let us know what you have tried, and Google is always the best place to start with problems you might have.

Comment: Thanks! I did check on google, that's how I got here. Your solution works, but only partially though. When I'm in stereo mode, they can only hear sounds from my computer. When on Mic as normal, they can hear only my voice. Never both at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I could be totally wrong - but I'm not sure the stereo mix is the issue?

If you check out the regular Windows Volume (right click speaker icon in lower right taskbar and 'open volume mixer') I find sometimes my computer arbitrarily mutes specific software for no apparent reason... could be something like this?

Keeps doing it to Spotify.... often most software programs have their own independent volume fader = so don't forget to scroll right within the mixer to see them all.

Hope that might help?  Also maybe see if there's a skype specific forum to try or see if they have live chat?

Good luck.